# Know the input and output internet usage per second of each process in ubuntu 20

Tags: 20.04, docker

I am using docker to provide a service but I discovered that some malicious people are carrying out denial of service attacks.

So what I would like to know is how to measure the outgoing bandwidth of a process to be able to determine if they are carrying out an attack and to be able to stop it or obtain some alternative to be able to stop any outgoing attack

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Done, I hope I have detailed well